# Nodejs: Bash can't find node?

Tags: bash, node.js

```
#!/bin/sh
exec node /opt/nodejs/first/app.js 1>>/opt/nodejs/first/log/output 2>>/opt/nodejs/first/log/error
```

This shell script throws an error:

```
exec: 2: node: not found
```

I'm trying to launch it on system boot:

```
sudo update-rc.d autostart.sh defaults 95
```

I'm doing something wrong?

Maybe boot level is wrong or order number, or something else?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set your `PATH` environment variable to include the directory where your `node` binary lives.  For starting on boot, what OS are you running?  I suggest Ubuntu where you can use the upstart system.  Here's a simple upstart script to make a node server work as a daemon.

```
description "start and stop your node.js server"
version "1.0"
author "You <you@yoursite.example>"

start on startup
respawn

env NODE_ENV=production
env PATH=/path/to/node/bin
chdir /path/to/your/app/root
exec su -c 'node app/server.js' www-data  >> var/log/stdout.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know `node`, but the typical error here is that the `PATH` variable at the time of execution of the script does not contain the path to your program. The easiest fix is to simply use the full path:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /path/to/node ...
```